# Error inflating class fragment when changing my data class

Tags: android, json, xml, kotlin

My app is working fine when using the data class that i'm currently using from an online exercise:
https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com/.
But when I try to change it to my own data class and json file (https://opendata.visitflanders.org/tourist/activities/breweries.json) i get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.marsrealestate, PID: 26103
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.marsrealestate/com.example.android.marsrealestate.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.android.marsrealestate:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.android.marsrealestate:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2571)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.android.marsrealestate:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.android.marsrealestate:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.android.marsrealestate:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.example.android.marsrealestate:navigation/nav_graph line 41
```

etc.
This is the data class that works fine:

```
@Parcelize
data class MarsProperty (
        val id: String,
        // used to map img_src from the JSON to imgSrcUrl in our class
        @Json(name = "img_src") val imgSrcUrl: String,
        val type: String,
        val price: Double) : Parcelable {
    val isRental
        get() = type == "rent"
}
```

This is the one i'm trying to use:

```
data class MarsProperty (
    val Name: String,
    val imagesURL: String,
    val street: String,
    val city_name: String,
    val phone: String
    )
```

My OverviewFragment

```
class OverviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: OverviewViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(OverviewViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = FragmentOverviewBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        binding.photosGrid.adapter = PhotoGridAdapter(PhotoGridAdapter.OnClickListener {
            viewModel.displayPropertyDetails(it)
        })

        viewModel.navigateToSelectedProperty.observe(this, Observer {
            if ( null != it ) {
                // Must find the NavController from the Fragment
                this.findNavController().navigate(OverviewFragmentDirections.actionShowDetail(it))
                // Tell the ViewModel we've made the navigate call to prevent multiple navigation
                viewModel.displayPropertyDetailsComplete()
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

My OverviewViewModel

```
class OverviewViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _properties = MutableLiveData<List<MarsProperty>>()

    val properties: LiveData<List<MarsProperty>>
        get() = _properties

    private val _navigateToSelectedProperty = MutableLiveData<MarsProperty>()
    val navigateToSelectedProperty: LiveData<MarsProperty>
        get() = _navigateToSelectedProperty

    init {
        getMarsRealEstateProperties()
    }

    private fun getMarsRealEstateProperties() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _properties.value = MarsApi.retrofitService.getProperties()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _properties.value = ArrayList()
            }
        }
    }

    fun displayPropertyDetails(marsProperty: MarsProperty) {
        _navigateToSelectedProperty.value = marsProperty
    }

    fun displayPropertyDetailsComplete() {
        _navigateToSelectedProperty.value = null
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

My nav_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/overviewFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/overviewFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.marsrealestate.overview.OverviewFragment"
        android:label="fragment_overview"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_overview" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_showDetail"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.marsrealestate.detail.DetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail">
        <argument
            android:name="selectedProperty"
            app:argType="com.example.android.marsrealestate.network.MarsProperty"
            />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

My fragment_overview.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.android.marsrealestate.overview.OverviewViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.android.marsrealestate.MainActivity">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/photos_grid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:listData="@{viewModel.properties}"
            app:spanCount="1"
            tools:itemCount="16"
            tools:listitem="@layout/grid_view_item" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

If you need any more files let me know.

Comment: You can't send non-parcelable classes are arguments. Is there a reason you didn't add the `@Parcelize` annotation to your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new `MarsProperty` class does not implement the `Parcelable` interface and does not have the `@Parcelize` annotation. I guess it can be an issue as the Navigation Component does not support passing such classes as destination arguments - they have to meet [some requirements](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a part of the data that you are using but making a data class of only the require parts is not a good idea.
Create a data class for the whole response and it should work.
There is a plugin for converting the response to a data class.

Go to `Settings -> Plugins -> Marketplace -> JSON To Kotlin Class`
[image: Plugin for converting the data class]

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `Parcelable` and add `@Parcelize` annotation.

```
@Parcelize
data class MarsProperty: Parcelable (
    val Name: String,
    val imagesURL: String,
    val street: String,
    val city_name: String,
    val phone: String
)
```

Your data class must implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` to pass arguments in Navigation Component.